# Designing an API to accept a generic output stream as a parameter

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I am designing an API using the LLVM library which will accept an output stream as one of its constructor parameters. The LLVM coding standards dictate the following:

> Use raw_ostream
>
> LLVM includes a lightweight, simple, and efficient stream
>   implementation in llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h, which provides all of
>   the common features of std::ostream. All new code should use
>   raw_ostream instead of ostream.
>
> Unlike std::ostream, raw_ostream is not a template and can be forward
>   declared as class raw_ostream. Public headers should generally not
>   include the raw_ostream header, but use forward declarations and
>   constant references to raw_ostream instances.

I must abide by the LLVM coding standards, so I am trying to accept a raw_ostream as a parameter in my constructor. I have tried passing a raw_ostream by reference and by pointer, but I receive the following error message at compile time:

> note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from
>   'llvm::raw_ostream &()' to 'llvm::raw_ostream &'...

What should my constructor look like to accept a parameter of type 'llvm::raw_ostream &()'? I would like to initialize a class member to this output stream.

Here is my current code:

**Constructor**

```
MyClass(raw_ostream &OS) : OutputStream(OS) {}
```

**Caller**

```
MyClass x = new MyClass(&outs);
```

`outs` is documented beginning at line 665 of [this link](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/raw__ostream_8cpp_source.html)

Comment: Show your existing constructor.

Comment: MyClass(const raw_ostream &OS) : OutputStream(OS) {}

Comment: Are you sure it should be const?

Comment: `OutputStream` is a `raw_ostream` or `raw_ostream &` ?

Comment: Just removed the const; same error.

Comment: OutputStream is a raw_ostream&

Comment: What is `OutputStream`? Is is an attribute or a base class?

Comment: It is a member of a class.

Comment: OK, I think it's best if you show all the relevant code, definition of the class including the member, maybe there is an error there we cannot see without the code. You should put it in the main text of the question.

Comment: I've added the relevant code.

Comment: I think my problem is I need to pass `outs()` as the constructor argument instead of `&outs`. It works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tons of examples within the LLVM source where `raw_ostream` is a function / method argument. It's almost always `(..., raw_ostream &OS, ...)`

Here's a representative example from `CodeGen/AsmPrinter/AsmPrinter.cpp`:

```
static void emitComments(const MachineInstr &MI, raw_ostream &CommentOS) {
  // ... code
}
```